# How to download a zip file in AngularJS / FilesaverJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, download, angularjs-http

i have a service function which return me 3 result files(2 text files, 1 zip file).

i want to check the header of the response to see if the file is a zip or a text to set the right configuration to download the file.

my controller resolved the promise from my service. if i download a text file -> the file says [object object] ..

i have seen in my browser that the response body is from content-type: text/plain

i am bit confused :/

controller :

```
$scope.getResult = function(rid) {
        console.log($scope.id);
        GetResultFile.getResult($scope.id, rid)
        .then(function (data, headers) {
            //console.log(headers(Content-type));
            console.log("Download erfolgreich");
            console.log(data.status);
            var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8'});
            FileSaver.saveAs(file, 'test.txt');

        }, function (data) {
            console.log("Download ERROR!");
            console.log(data.status);
        })
    };
```

service :

```
.factory('GetResultFile',
['$http', '$q',
function ($http, $q) {

    var service = {};
    service.getResult = function(id, rid) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http
        .get('http://localhost:9999/v1/jmeter/' + id + '/results/' + rid, {cache: false})
        .then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            if(data.status == 200) {
                console.log(data.status);
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }
            else {
                deferred.reject(data);
            }
        });
        return deferred.promise;                
    }
    return service;
```

view:

```
<span ng-show="dataTable">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="r in results">
            <td><a href="" ng-click="getResult(r.id)" download>{{r.name}}</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</span>
```

Update:

this is my service where i set the responsetype to arraybuffer

```
.factory('GetZip',
['$http', '$q',
function ($http, $q) {

    var service = {};
    service.getZip = function(id, rId) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http
        .get('http://localhost:9999/v1/jmeter/' + id + '/results/' + rId, {cache: false, responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
        .then(function(response) {
            if(response.status == 200) {
                console.log(response.status);
                deferred.resolve(response);
            }
            else {
                deferred.reject(response);
            }
        });
        return deferred.promise;                
    }
    return service;
```

this is my call in controller :

```
$scope.getResult = function(rId, rName) {
        console.log($scope.id);
        console.log(rName);
        GetResultFile.getResult($scope.id, rId)
        .then(function(response) {
            var data = "";
            var headerType = "";
            data = response.data;
            headerType = response.headers('content-type');
            console.log(response.headers('content-type'));
            console.log("Download erfolgreich");
            console.log(response);
            // zip data need to be handle with a binary stream
            if(headerType == 'application/zip;charset=UTF-8') {
                GetZip.getZip($scope.id, rId)
                .then(function(response) {
                    var file = new Blob([response.data], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
                    FileSaver.saveAs(file, rName);
                    console.log("zipper");
                }, function(response) {
                    console.log("Download ERROR");
                    console.log(response.status);
                })
            } else {
                var file = new Blob([data], {type: headerType});
                FileSaver.saveAs(file, rName);
                console.log("else");
            }
        }, function(response) {
            console.log("Download ERROR!");
            console.log(response.status);
        })
    };
```

}])

but if i download the zip file, its still corrupt and a error while extract the zip -.-

Comment: So what's the actual problem currently? The title mentions zip files but you're asking about text files in the question. Could you expand on `..the file says [object object]`?

Comment: ups sorry, text files and zip file, i will edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have 2 separate rest services on backend for this so instead of serving all files at the same time and holding them in browser, you should retrieve list of available files from one rest endpoint and then on user's click retrieve specific file from another rest endpoint. Your service for file could look something like this:

```
function downloadFile(src) {
  let header, startIndex, filename;
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: src,
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,application/pdf;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
      'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': 1
    },
    responseType: 'blob'
  }).then(function (successResponse) {
    header = unescape(successResponse.headers()['content-disposition']);
    startIndex = header.indexOf('filename=');
    filename = header.slice(startIndex + 10,-1);
    try{
      saveAs(successResponse.data, filename);
    }
    catch(error){
      // FileSaver error
    }
  }, function (errorResponse) {
    // Server error has occurred during file downloading.
}
```

Where you need to specify response type to be blob. Variable src in this example would be specific endpoind serving desired file (here it's served from controller based on data retrieved from list of files available but you can build it here if you want based on file's id or something). In this case backend is serving full file name in exposed header so you can extract it and save file with it's proper name and format. Extraction in this example was for specific rest response but you should be able to change it to suite your needs.

Example: content disposition header would be string, something like:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="picture.png"
```

In this case service would extract that name and Filesaver would save file "picture.png".

Comment: can you check my update of the question ? still not working ..

Comment: @Kai in your controller, var file=.... what is data? you are doing nothing with response, it should be something like response.data also make sure rName is proper name of file, I'm currently not sure where your're getting it from.

Comment: data = response.data and rName is the name of the file from the view, the name is right and the data looks good, but if i unzip the data, a error comes up -.-

Comment: okay i have fixe it !

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

### How to download a zip file in AngularJS

To download a binary file type such as a zip file, it is important to set the `responseType` before doing the XHR.

```
var config = { responseType: "blob" };

var promise = $http.get(url, config);

promise
  .then(function onSuccess(response) {
    // Handle success
    var data = response.data;
    var status = response.status;
    var statusText = response.statusText;
    var headers = response.headers;
    var config = response.config;
    ...
  }).catch(function onError(response) {
    // Handle error
    var data = response.data;
    var status = response.status;
    var statusText = response.statusText;
    var headers = response.headers;
    var config = response.config;
    ...
  });
```

For more information, see [MDN Web API Reference - XHR responseType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType).

Comment: can you check my update of the question, still a error